# Immutable structs in ASP.NET MVC model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

If I use an immutable struct in my model, i.e.:

```
public struct ImmutableStruct
{
    private readonly int firstProperty;

    public ImmutableStruct(int firstProperty) : this()
    {
        this.firstProperty = firstProperty
    }

    public int FirstProperty { get { return firstProperty; } }
}
```

The model fragment:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public ImmutableStruct structProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The view fragment:

```
@model SomeModel

<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(x = x.structProperty.FirstProperty)
</div>
```

The model binder does not seem to be able to bind any data when posting back to the controller.  Does this mean (1) that immutable structs should not be used, (2) need to use a custom model binder, (3) or I need to do something else instead?

Comment: In what context are you using this? Are you trying to bind to a property of type `ImmutableStruct`?

Comment: Yes, I've added some code fragments to clarify.

Comment: As AaronLS has pointed out below, You need a parameterless constructor, and in any case a setter is required to bind a to a property on post back. Not really clear what you trying to achieve with this.

Comment: Our project has some legacy structs that we wanted to hook into MVC that are similar to this (except they have multiple properties). Wasn't sure of the most appropriate course of action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC requires a default parameterless constructor as far as I am aware.  Your constructor does not qualify because it requires a parameter.  MVC does binding via properties, and your property has no setter.

I believe a custom model binder will solve your problem, allowing you to call the constructor.  Seems alot more trouble than it's worth though, especially since you'll probably have to modify your custom model binder anytime you add properties to your class.  But I'll leave that up to you to decide.

The details of how to do model binding to a parameterized constructor are exemplified in this model binder:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13535545/84206

Notice `return new Company(customProfile);` would be similar to `new ImmutableStruct(someValue)`

Comment: One could create a more genericized custom model binder using reflection based on the assumption that every model would have a constructor with parameters corresponding to each property in the class.  I wouldn't have said that's any worse an assumption than MVC's default behaviour of assuming every model is mutable and has a default constructor.

Comment: @MattArnold True.  I used AutoMapper for awhile, and it was something I had imagined was possible, was glad someone made it, but after a couple years I came to the conclusion it's easier to just have explicit mappings and use interfaces to avoid a multitude of duplicate/all-combinations mappings.  When the "magic" of reflective/dynamic mapping doesn't work, it's often difficult to find the problem. It's alot easier to just have a tangible `ToModel<ISomeReturnModel>(ISomeFromEntity fromEntity)` and step through all the child object mappings until you encounter the property/item that didn't map.

Comment: My thinking was along the lines that MVC's Default Model Binder must use some form of reflection also to perform postback-data-to-property-mapping.  There is still the added issue of an assignment constructor's parameters having a naming convention used by the custom model binder (e.g. every parameter name is a camel case variant of the pascal case property name it maps to) which could catch someone out if they decide to use a different convention.  I do wonder if a T4-Template-Generated Model Binder for each model might be a better solution as this would then have compile-time type safety.