# jQuery Validation: Validate method not invoked

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-plugins

In my ASP.NET MVC 4.0 Web application, the jQuery validation's validate method is never invoked and hence validation is not happening. I guess it must be some subtle thing that I am missing.

The html generated is as follows ...

```
<html>
 <head>        
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form id="CreateForm" method="post">    
   <div class="editor-label">
    <label for="Customer_FirstName">FirstName</label>
   </div>
   <div class="editor-field">
    <input class="text-box single-line" id="Customer_FirstName" name="Customer.FirstName" type="text" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Customer.FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
   </div>
   <p>       
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />   
   </p>
  </form>
  <script>
   $(document.ready(function () {
    $('#CreateForm').validate({
     rules: {
      "Customer.FirstName": "required"     
     },
     messages: {
      "Customer.FirstName": "Enter first name"
     }
    });
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have included the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` file. Why on earth not just add the `[Required]` attribute to the `Customer.FirstName` property and have all this handled out of the box (no script required at all)

Comment: missing `)` in `$(document).` - you have `$(document.`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e91nx5us/1/

Comment: missing ) was a typo. Removing the reference to jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js worked !!! Many thanks.

Comment: Make sure you enabled the client side validation and unobtrusive scripts.

Comment: @Stephen, I want to keep my model (POCO) attribute free. I am happy to add attributes to my view model. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28891715/overloaded-viewmodel-constructor-and-httppost-in-asp-net-mvc . If I add a property named FirstName in my viewmodel, I get the parameterless constructor not defined error

Comment: Regarding the link in your last comment. That is not a view model. A view model contains only those properties you want to display/edit in a view. It is not a container to hold your data model. You should be using view models correctly. It will be far less code and more robust and easier to debug that manually adding rules in the view, and then having to repeat manual validation in the controller.